# Местоимения ВЫ, ВАШ пишутся с прописной или строчной буквы?

Tags: местоимения, прописная-строчная

Как правильно написать поздравление "Поздравляем Вас и Ваш коллектив с..." или "Поздравляем Вас и ваш коллектив с..."

Comment: @Илья Муромец, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Местоимения Вы, Ваш пишутся с прописной буквы при обращении к одному лицу в текстах следующих жанров:

а) личное письмо (адресат - одно лицо);

б) официальные документы, адресованные одному лицу;

в) анкеты, рекламные листовки (текст, адресованный неконкретному лицу).

При обращении к нескольким лицам или неопределенному кругу лиц (например, при обращении к читательской аудитории газеты или журнала, при обращении к посетителям сайта, в объявлении, адресованном широкому кругу лиц, и т. п.) местоимения вы, ваш пишутся со строчной буквы: Дорогие подписчики! Напоминаем вам, что...; На портале ''Грамота.ру'' опубликован новый интерактивный диктант. Проверьте вашу грамотность!

Можно предложить такое мнемоническое правило: если перед местоимением вы можно вставить обращение в форме единственного числа, то написание местоимения с большой буквы уместно: уважаемый коллега, предлагаем Вам... Но: уважаемые коллеги, предлагаем вам...
***(Источник: Грамота.ру).***

***Таким образом, если ваш текст обращен к одному лицу, Вы, Ваш  пишите с прописной, в ином случае - со строчной.***